# Specifying hibernate mapping file

Tags: hibernate

I have the following file directory

```
WebContent/search.jsp
WebContent/xml/Car.hbm.xml
```

I'm creating instantiating the Configuration object as follows:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
                    .addResource("xml/Car.hbm.xml");
```

But it is resulting in `MappingException due to Car.hbm.xml file not found`.

What's the correct way of specifying the path of the mapping file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic). If you move the xml folder into WEB-INF directory, the content will be in classpath. Later just do the following, it should take care of finding the xmlfile.

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration()
                    .addResource("Car.hbm.xml");
```

(Or)

Usually the content directly under WebContent are not in classpath unless you specify it in the eclipse project `Java build path > sources > Add Folder`  and select the `xml` folder. And do the exact same step mentioned above.